# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{1}{n})$ is divergent/convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be  a  continious  function  such that  $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx < \infty$

Then  choose the correct option

$1.$ The sequence $\{f(\frac{1}{n})\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded

$2$.$f(\frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$3$ The series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{1}{n})$  is  divergent

$4$ The series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{1}{n})$  is  convergent

My attempt : If i take $f_n(x) = x^n$  then option $1, 2, 4$ will correct

is its true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4) is false: take  $f=1$. 3) is false because $f=0$ satisfies the hypothesis. 2) is false: take $f=1$. 1) is true by continuity. Hence 1) is true and others are all false.

Comment: Pliz tell  function also  @Kavi  sir

Comment: Note that $\int_0^{1} f(x)dx <\infty$ for any continuous function $f$.

Comment: @jasmine I have to leave now. I will given an explicit definition of  $f$ later.

Answer (score 1):

An example will not show an option to be correct. For an option to be correct, it must be correct for *all* possible $f$, and you can't possibly check the functions one by one like that.

However, an example can show an option to be *incorrect*. So you haven't shown 1, 2, 4 to be true, you've found 3 to be untrue. Keep trying other functions to see whether the other seem to be true as well. For instance, what about $f(x) = 1$? What option is / options are proven to be false by that one?

Also note that $f_n$ is unfortunate notation. You're already using $n$ for the index in the sequence, and using $n$ to index a family of functions as well is considered bad practice as now whenever you mention $n$, we don't know *which* $n$ that refers to, so your text becomes more difficult to read. It might get you into trouble, like thinking that the sequence $f_1(1/1), f_2(1/2), f_3(1/3), \ldots$ is somehow relevant to this problem.

Comment: if$ f(x) =1 $  then  option 4 and 2 is  discard But  i need some sequence function $ f_n$

Comment: @jasmine No, you don't need some $f_n$. Nowhere in that problem statement is a sequence of functions mentioned. It's a sequence of points, and an arbitrary function evaluated at those points. It could be any function, but it's just one at a time. Not a sequence of them.

Comment: thanks u @Arthur  got it now